# Resolving GitHub users via organization email

Tags: github, backstage

I'm trying to implement the validation presented in the [Backstage](https://backstage.io/docs/integrations/github/org#resolving-github-users-via-organization-email) documentation.

However, I am unable to apply. I think some guidelines are missing.

Has anyone successfully implemented this validation and could explain here?

Comment: Can you share your code or the challenges you are facing?